# how to setup grunt in webstorm on windows

Tags: command-line, gruntjs, webstorm

I am Using *Webstorm (PHPStorm)* on *Windows 7*. On the actual project we are using grunt to concatenate javascript and css and also for several other build processes.

I tried to setup the grunt command as an external run command in Webstorm. The settings i tried for that are:

```
Name: grunt  
Parameters: none  
WorkingDirectory: $ProjectFileDir$
```

So now when I am trying to start my external run command in Webstorm, I always get the error

```
> grunt
Cannot run program "grunt" (in directory "C:\Users\jawidmer\workspaces\projectname"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

When I open my command line tool and navigate to the project folder, I can start grunt without any problems.

I already searched in google and tried all kinds of different combinations of settings but non of them worked..

*Do you have any ideas, what I have to change to be able to start grunt from external run commands in Webstorm?*

Thanks
Jan

Comment: Provide **FULL PATH** to grunt executable file (including file extension). It's obvious that Windows does not know what `grunt` is when launched from IDE. Providing full path to it (or, at VERY LEAST, adding an extension (cmd/bat/exe or whatever that grunt file has)) should definitely help. Also -- restarting computer may help (in case PATH variable was not propagated properly -- in case if it was modified, of course).

Comment: the weird thing is, that I never added Grunt to the path variable. It just works within my project folder..so I couldnt really figure out, where the file location is exactly.

My Grund Module is at the following path:
C:\Users\jawidmer\workspaces\projectname\node_modules\grunt

In this folder there is also a Gruntfile.js. 

I already tried to set the path to that folder but it didn't seem to make a difference, also the error message didn't change at all..

Comment: There is a grunt.cmd file, but its located in C:\Users\jawidmer\AppData\Roaming\npm. I also tried to point the path to that cmd..

Comment: `C:\Users\jawidmer\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd` should be the one -- use it in **Program** field of External Tools. The PATH environment variable is getting updated when you install `nodejs` first time -- if it's not fresh install then ignore this moment.

Comment: Alternatively you may try: Program: `cmd.exe`; Parameters: `/C "C:\Users\jawidmer\AppData\Roaming\npm\grunt.cmd"`; Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$`

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions. The second works kinda..

It seems to find the grunt command, but it only starts to execute one task, than it exits with a strange error code:
Running "concat:inline_scripts" (concat) task

Process finished with exit code -1'073'741'819 at 15:18:38.
Execution time: 835 ms.

Comment: For me it sounds like when launching from IDE, grunt is *unable to find some files or something* (access rights issue or some other restrictions??). I have never faced this myself ... but then -- I just installed grunt to run it for already made tasks, nothing more -- my experience is very limited in this regard. For me it went all smooth (Windows 7 x64 SP1; I'm user with admin rights; no UAC). Cannot advise you any better than I did so far -- maybe somebody else can.

Comment: mmh i installed it freshly like a week ago..including node js and everything.. ok, thanks for your help Maybe somebody else knows something.. :-)

Comment: Hey Jan, have a look at this: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5468081#5468081 Not sure if it will help, but it might be related to your problem.

Answer (score 6):

By your description, I assume that the same way I configured it in my WebStorm installation should work just fine for you too:

[image: Grunt WebStorm configuration]

I hope it helps.

---

**UPDATE**

It seems that if you add `> %TEMP%\grunt & type %TEMP%\grunt & del %TEMP%\grunt` to Parameters (like shown in the updated image), the build errors will be shown.

If you need to configure a task (for example `grunt watch`), the Parameters field must be the following:

```
watch > %TEMP%\grunt & type %TEMP%\grunt & del %TEMP%\grunt
```

Tip taken from [here](http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5468081)

Comment: Hi.. I tried exactly your configuration and it seems that grunt starts but then it exits on the first task with the following message:


> grunt.cmd
Running "concat:inline_scripts" (concat) task

Process finished with exit code -1'073'741'819 at 09:17:40.
Execution time: 1'578 ms.

Comment: Than that means that an error happened in one of your tasks. I have not figured out yet why the error doesn't get printed there.

Comment: yeah seems like..i guess i will just continue to use it in a separate command line window.. Danks for your help.

Comment: Here is a RegEx to use in the Output Filters: `$FILE_PATH$[ \t]*[:;,\[\(\{<]$LINE$(?:[:;,\.]$COLUMN$)?.*` Works with stacktraces and some compile errors. See also [jshint-path-reporter](https://github.com/Bartvds/jshint-path-reporter#example-output)

Comment: @user2477219 I updated the answer with an workaround; take a look!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this variant will be useful for somebody:
Settings -> External Tools

[image]

With this tool I can right-click folder in project and in context menu select grunt -> build

Answer (score 0):

As I had problems with the path of node and grunt in linux. I've decide to add the following in Settings->External Tools, I guess in windows can be done in the same way (PHPstorm 7, in the same dialog as the prior answers):

Name: grunt     Group: Node

Program: `/opt/nodes/current/bin/node`              (my path to node files)
Parameters: `/my/directory/node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt watch`      (my path to grunt-cli binary and the parameter to the task of grunt)
Working directory: `/home/user/project/`            (my path to Gruntfile.js)